# Rss builder definition and usage

Tags: rss, rss-reader, rss2

I am going through various docs for reading about rss builder but i am not sure what exactly it is about and i am not able to get the download link for ubuntu.

Can any one help me?
How can i download rss builder for Ubuntu.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is some software for generating an RSS feed (so not really a programming problem anyway so off-topic for here), which is written for Windows (so doesn't run on Ubuntu unless we want to start talking about how you run Windows software under Linux in general terms … also off-topic) and for which the homepage for seems to have been replaced with something unrelated (suggesting that the software is defunct anyway). So, in short: You probably shouldn't, and if you really really want to, then superuser would probably be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks  for  u  r  comment